# How to horizontally center floating inline-block elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to have two inline-block `div`s centered, in a 100% - width container.

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWHrF/)

the divs on the right (*Left not floated* and *Right not floated*) works just as I want.

Therefore, if the divs left and right does not have `float:left;`, it works.

But I need those `float:left;`'s to cover the contents, so how can I center two floated inline block div's?

### P.S.

I also tried `float:right;` on `div#right` but that seperates the divs to the edges of container, whereas I want them to coincide on the center.

### P.S. 2

Of course I tried `margin:auto;` on div#left and div#right, still the same.

Comment: What do you mean by `to cover the contents`?

Comment: the div should have enough width and height to contain whatever content it has. I always achieve that by float:left;. Is it right ?

Comment: left_not_floated and right_not_floated appear to be containing their contents just fine. What is it that they are not doing for you?

Comment: The inline blocks will enclose their content in a shrink-to-fit manner similar to a table cell.  You don't need floats in this case.  You get the centering using text-align: center as you demonstrated.  Therefore, what is missing? Please clarify!

Comment: You are right, I don't need floats to fit the content, don't know how did I do this mistake :) Thanks for all the help !